# XSLT copy XML file, change value of one attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0, tei

Note: edited with updated code, producing new problems with namespaces.

Using XSLT 3.0 and Saxon HE, I'm copying an XML document and in copying it I need to increment the value of attribute `@n` in the element `<div type="foo" n="0300">`. In this case I want to increment `@n` by 1. This is the current code:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//tei:div[@type='foo']">
   <div type="foo">
        <xsl:attribute name="n">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@n + 1,'0000')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
   </div type>
</xsl:template>
```

It should produce:

```
<div type="foo" n="0002"/>
```

But rather produces the following:

```
<div xmlns="" xmlns:ntei="http://www.example.org/ns/nonTEI" type="foo" n="0301"/>
```

I am working with the TEI namespace. How do I prevent these attributes being added: `xmlns="" xmlns:ntei="http://www.example.org/ns/nonTEI"` ?

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has been answered. For someone new (like me) coming along and seeing an answer that only addresses part of the question, it's almost impossible to disentangle what's going on. If you have a problem with namespaces that seems to be completely unrelated to your original question, so please ask a new question. (But read up on XSLT and namespaces first, because it's almost certainly been asked and answered before).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XML document,

```
<div type="foo" n="0300"/>
```

when input to this XSLT 3.0 transformation,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="@n">
    <xsl:attribute name="n">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. + 1,'0000')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will yield this output XML document,

```
<div type="foo" n="0301"/>
```

as requested.

Comment: Works great. I removed the excessive namespace declarations I was using, and that solved the other 'wrinkle' (your comment duly noted). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="div[@type='foo']">
    <div type='foo'>
        <xsl:attribute name="n"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@n + 1,'0000')"/></xsl:attribute>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @mg-kedzie That almost works. It produces the following: <div xmlns="" xmlns:ntei="http://www.example.org/ns/nonTEI" type="registry_ordinal" n="0002"/> . I am working within the TEI namespace.